# If the weak limit of sequence of projections is again a projection then strong limit exists.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

> Let $\{P_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of orthogonal projections on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ such that weak limit of the sequence is again a projection $P$ i.e. $\left \langle x, P_n x \right \rangle \rightarrow \left \langle x, P x \right \rangle.$ Show that $P_n \rightarrow P$ in strong operator topology i.e. $P_n x \rightarrow P x.$

What we have given is that $\|P_n x\|^2 \rightarrow \|Px\|^2.$ But I don't understand how does it follow the result. Any help in this regard will be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using polarization, $\langle y,P_nx\rangle\to\langle y,Px\rangle$ for all $x,y$. Then you have
\begin{align}
\|P_nx-Px\|^2
&=\langle P_nx-Px,P_nx-Px\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\langle P_nx,P_nx\rangle+\langle Px,Px\rangle-2\operatorname{Re} \langle Px,P_nx\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\langle x,P_nx\rangle+\langle x,Px\rangle-2\operatorname{Re} \langle Px,P_nx\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&\to2\langle x,Px\rangle-2\operatorname{Re}\langle Px,Px\rangle
=2\langle x,Px\rangle-2\langle x,Px\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=0
\end{align}

Comment: Is this result true for arbitrary self-adjoint operators? After analyzing your answer I can conclude that we can have the result iff $T_n^2 \xrightarrow {\text {WOT}} T^2$ whenever $T_n \xrightarrow {\text {WOT}} T.$ But is it necessarily true for self-adjoint operators? In case of projections we are through because projections are idempotent. But there are self-adjoint operators which are not projections.

Comment: No. Every selfajoint $T$ with $\|T\|≤1$ is a wot limit of projections. So if you choose $T$ with $T^2\ne T$ , you have a net $\{P_j\}$ of projections with $P_n\to T$ wot, but $P_n^2\to T\ne T^2$.